# Which is correct: "a same...of" or "the same...of"?

Tags: grammar

Examples:

1. They boys have a/the same weight of 40 kg.
2. The roads have a/the same distance of 10 km.

We would normally say "**the** same...", but "**a** weight/distance **of**..."

Which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Neither of them seems natural. We would normally say

> All the boys weigh 40kg

But

> The boys have the same weight, 40 kg.

would also be possible

> All the roads are 10 km long

Roads do not have distance they have length. They may be at a distance from the speaker or from some other feature.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!